# What single type can refer to hyper HttpConnector and HttpsConnector?

Tags: rust, hyper

Hyper's `HttpConnector` and hyper_tls's `HttpsConnector` clearly implement a common trait (or traits). I've studied their implementations and I haven't been able to come up with the right type (or alias) that would allow me to pass instances of either struct to a function like in the program below. It looks like `Tower::Service<Url>` is the right Trait, but I have failed to come up with the right answer and could really use help.

```rust
use hyper::{client::connect::HttpConnector, service::Service, Uri};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;

// What type should param c have here for this program to compile?
fn with_connector(c: ????) {}

fn main() {
    with_connector(HttpConnector::new());
    with_connector(HttpsConnector::new());
}
```

Relevant implementations for:

[HttpConnector](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/client/connect/http.rs#L230)

[HttpsConnector](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper-tls/blob/master/src/client.rs#L97)

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.13"
hyper-tls = "0.4.3"
```

The use case is that I'm writing a connector of my own that will contain an instance of either one of these as a delegate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's using `tower_service::Service` underneath, but it's being re-exported as `hyper::service::Service`, so maybe use that?

Comment: The issue I have is with the generics and associated types on that Service trait, it's fairly nuts. I don't know how to specify the type to cover both `HttpConnector` and `HttpsConnector`.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I found a fix that the compiler likes. See the solution to this Q. It's kind of ugly and not obvious, but I'm a Rust learner and could be my unfamiliarity. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by copying the generic type definitions common to both connectors. The result is still crazy ugly to my eyes: hard to believe anyone could come up with this without copy/pasting like I did. But maybe someone with a deep familiarity with the various traits involved would have no problem?

```
use hyper::{client::connect::HttpConnector, service::Service, Uri};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};

type BoxError = Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>;

fn with_connector<T>(conn: T)
where
    T: Service<Uri>,
    T::Response: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Send + Unpin,
    T::Future: Send + 'static,
    T::Error: Into<BoxError>,
{
    // do something with conn
}

fn main() {
    let http = HttpConnector::new();
    with_connector(http);

    let https = HttpsConnector::new();
    with_connector(https);
}
```

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.13"
hyper-tls = "0.4.3"
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
```